# How did my coworker manage to make git checkout move files?

Tags: git

Normally when you:

1. `git checkout foo`
2. Modify a file
3. `git checkout bar`

Git will tell you that you can't change branches because you have un-committed modifications. (I don't have the exact message in front of me, but it's something to that effect).  You then normally use `git stash` to get rid of those modifications, and you're on your merry way.

My coworker (who is new to Git and therefore is not intentionally doing anything advanced) doesn't have that behavior.  On her machine, when she does `git checkout bar`, it just moves the modifications that she made on `foo` into `bar`.  This is very confusing to me, as I've been using Git for at least a year now and never seen it behave that way.

What could my coworker possibly have done to make it so that Git simply moves un-added/un-committed modified files between branches, rather than complaining and requiring `git stash`?

Comment: Which versions of git do you and your colleage use?

Comment: Does she use the -f flag?  Are the files she is modifying tracked in both branches?

Comment: My co-worker is running 1.7.0.4.  I'm running 1.7.5.4, but I've run other versions (not sure exactly which, but my old workstation was on a 2+ year old version of Ubuntu, so it was probably running a significantly older git) and I've never seen this behavior.

Comment: She did not use the -f flag (or the -m one for that matter, which seems like it might cause this).  I believe the files were tracked in both branches (they had been added/committed in previous commits on both branches, if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I just wrote up the following text here for coworkers yesterday who are new to Git. Hope it helps.)

If you have made changes to files on branch A and want to switch to branch B (which is unrelated), then it’s a good idea to commit the changes to branch A first. This way, the changes will still be on branch A when you come back to it later. (Another option is called “stashing”, which is useful in some situations – see http://schacon.github.com/git/git-stash.html for more information.)

If you don’t commit the changes first, then there are two situations that can arise. Consider a file “file.txt”, and branches A and B. The two situations are:

1. The latest version of file.txt on branch A and branch B is identical. In this case, a “git checkout B” will carry over the changes to file.txt to your working directory after successfully switching to branch B. This can be useful for things like changes to platform configuration files. Git will list the files carried over in this way in the output of the “git checkout” command.
2. The latest versions of file.txt on branch A and branch B are different. When you ask to switch branches to branch B, git will refuse to switch branches because doing so would overwrite your changes to file.txt. You’ll get a message from git saying that you must commit (or stash) the conflicting file(s) first.

If you have more than one changed file, then any file in situation (2) will prevent a branch switch.

Finally, if you want to discard modifications to a file, use a command like “git checkout -- file.txt”. This will throw away any uncommitted modifications to file.txt and restore it to the latest committed version from your current branch.

Comment: Ahhhhh ... she was moving between two divergent branches, but it's entirely possible the modified files were the same in both branches.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" is actually what you co-worker sees. When there is some modification in your working directory and you switch to another branch, the changes will be available on that branch as well.

When you do get the message that you cannot switch is when the branch you are on and the branch you are switching to have diverged ( with respect to the files that are modified in the working directory) As long as the branches you are switching between have the same version for the files that are modified in the working directory, you will be able to switch branches.

Test:

```
git init .
touch a
git add a
git commit -m "adding a"
git branch temp
vi a #add something
git checktout temp # allows you to change
git commit -am "content in a"
vi a #add more content
git checkout master #won't allow you to change!
```

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense, except ... the two branches she was moving between were divergent.  In fact, the next thing we did after observing this weirdness was a git merge between the two branches, and it actually did a merge (with lots of changed files), so the two couldn't possibly have been at the same commit.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @machineghost - I might not have worded it properly. I have changed it. Key point is, the diverging is wrt to the files modified.

Comment: Gotcha; between your explanation and Greg's I think I get it now ... wish I could award the answer to you both.